# Making depending ComboBoxes using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, combo-box

How do I make comboBoxes depending using PyQGIS?

I have two comboBoxes one is for selecting the province and the second is about parks (only the parks that belong to the province will be on the second comboBox list.

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line , in runself.dlg.comboBox_changed(0)
AttributeError: 'XDialog' object has no attribute 'comboBox_changed'
```

```
def comboBox_changed(self, index):
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()

    park = self.layers[0].layer()
    selected_province = self.dlg.comboBox.currentText()
    filter = f"Commune='{selected_province}'" # Field name for Province in park layer
    for p in park.getFeatures(filter):
        self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItem(str(p["Nom"])) # park Name in park layer

def run(self):

    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = UrbanParksDialog()
    #Fetch the currently loaded layers
    self.layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()

    #Clear the contents of the comboBox from previous runs
    self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()

    #Populate cummuns comboBox 
    cum = self.layers[1].layer()
    for c in cum.getFeatures():
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(c.attributes()[1])       

    # Populate park s comboBox
    park = self.layers[0].layer()
    for p in park.getFeatures():
        self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItem(str(p.attributes()[0]))

    cum = self.layers[1].layer()

    for c in cum.getFeatures():
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(c["nom"]) # field name in cum layer

    
    self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboBox_changed)
    self.dlg.comboBox_changed(0)
```

Comment: In your parks layer, do you have an attribute which records what province each park belongs to?

Comment: Yes Ben, in the parks layer i have two attributes park's name and the province .

Comment: So sorry. I made a mistake (copy/paste issue, I guess). I fixed it. Change `self.dlg.comboBox_changed(0) ` to `self.dlg.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please provide a minimal plugin producing the same issue with a sample data.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I dunno how to thank you  I tried many codes I searched on the internet to try to making them depending on each other Thank you so much it works perfectly

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I have a little problem in the first combo box that is the provinces are duplicated example if I have two provinces X and Y in the dataset of province layer ,Then they are shown in the list like this  X and then Y and then X and then Y

Comment: This is a new issue. Please ask a new question about it using "Ask Question" button.

Comment: okay I will do thanks for the help wish you all the best

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you have to define a slot function (`comboBox_changed`) and set the park combobox values (`comboBox_2`) within the function. For this, you need to use `currentIndexChanged` signal of `comboBox` (provinces).

You can use the following sample script.

```py
def comboBox_changed(self, index):
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()

    park = self.layers[0].layer()
    selected_province = self.dlg.comboBox.currentText()
    filter = f"nom='{selected_province}'" # Field name for Province in park layer
    for p in park.getFeatures(filter):
        self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItem(str(p["Nom"])) # park Name in park layer

def run(self):

    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = UrbanParksDialog()
    #Fetch the currently loaded layers
    self.layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()

    #Clear the contents of the comboBox from previous runs
    self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()

    #Populate cummuns comboBox 

    cum = self.layers[1].layer()
    for c in cum.getFeatures():
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(c.attributes()[1])       

    # Populate park s comboBox
    park = self.layers[0].layer()


    for p in park.getFeatures():
        self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItem(str(p.attributes()[0]))

    cum = self.layers[1].layer()

    for c in cum.getFeatures():
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(c["Province"]) # field name in cum layer

    self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboBox_changed)
    self.dlg.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,. I think I put it on in the wrong place here is the code error that i get                                                                                                                       self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboBox_changed)
AttributeError: 'UrbanParks' object has no attribute 'comboBox_changed'

Comment: Since we don’t know how your whole script looks like, it is hard to say where to put it. I guess you try to make a plugin.

Comment: yes I'm trying to build a plugin.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, all I can say for now that `comboBox_changed` should be within the class.

Comment: I've updated my question with the section of code for populating.

Comment: You must have added the the script in the answer to the `run` method. So, you encountered the error. I've edited the answer. Put the `comboBox_changed` method before `cum = layers[1].layer()`.

Comment: In first case of the answer, `comboBox_changed` should have had the same indentation of the `run` method.

Comment: I edited the code and i have an error I tried to put the    cum = layers[1].layer()        
    for c in cum.getFeatures():
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(c["Province"]) # field name in cum layer

    self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboBox_changed)
    self.dlg.comboBox_changed(0)
    within the comboBox_change but it doesn't work neitheir

Comment: I've updated the answer. Add `self.` before all `layers[?].layer`.

Comment: I've updated the code  once again , I can see the plugin shortcut but it does'nt running

Comment: I edited the question section; @Kadir Thank you for your suggestion I tried the code and I  tried the code that you suggested and I got this error                              
 Traceback (most recent call last): File , in run self.dlg.comboBox_changed(0) AttributeError: 'XDialog' object has no attribute 'comboBox_changed'